# layout reduce after opening the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, percentage, android-constraintlayout

[image: layout samples]
Hello. I have some problem.

I have a layout, it consists of EditText and RelativeLayout, which have a fixed height in %, and also GridView, which is located between them match parent (match constraint).

All is well, while there is no keyboard. When the keyboard appears % is not counted from the entire screen, but from the part where there is no keyboard. I need to change the size of the GridView at the appearance of the keyboard, and the remaining elements calculated in % did not change.

Before that, I calculated the height in pixels as% of the screen height and set it programmatically. But I want to do this at the layout level. Really so it is impossible to make.

I tried to use ConstraintLayout with guidline layout_constraintGuide_percent and PercentageRelativeLayout like root view - uselessly. Change activity windowSoftInputMode in manifest too.

**Layout xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.ActivityAllApps">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlTabTitleAllApps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/qlTabTitle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:background="@drawable/background_action_bar9">

    <include layout="@layout/include_sortings"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTest"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibSettingsMenu"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rlSorts"
        android:onClick="onTestButton2Click"
        android:text="T"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibSettingsMenu"
        style="@style/MenuButtonSettings"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onSettingsMenuClick"
        tools:background="@drawable/settings_menu_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvAllApps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etSearch"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rlTabTitleAllApps"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSearch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_app"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_edit_text9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/qlSearch"
    tools:background="@drawable/search_app_background9"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/qlTabTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/constraint_tab_top"/>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/qlSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/constraint_all_search"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get what you want is to put your header and footers in custom views.  In those custom views, override their onMeasure to look at the size of the screen and calculate their heights from that.  Then use a layout that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <CustomHeaderView layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <FrameLayout layout_below="customHeaderView"  layout_above="customFooterView">
        //Your center here
    </FrameLayout>
    <CustomFooterView layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That will give you your fixed size top and bottom, with the center part fitting as best it can inside (I assume you have a scroll view in there somewhere.

Use this with the softInputMode resize.  But there's no easy way to get the behavior you want without some sort of trick like this, Android doesn't support it natively.